# Running Xcode Project on Device

Tags: ios, xcode

First off, I don't have a Developer Account. Now, I used to run my Xcode Project on my device without dev account successfully until Beta 5 and  of Xcode 6 came out. Since the release of Beta 5 and Beta 6, Xcode successfully builds and installs the app on my device but when I run the app, the app crashes. Did Apple Changed the way project compiles if code signing required is set to NO?

Answer (score 0):

To run on a device, you must have entitlements. To get entitlements, you must have a developer account. If you've been running on a device without a developer account, you must have found a loophole; you should never have been able to do that. They closed a loophole you should never have been using? Fine. That's good, not bad.

Comment: (except jailbroken devices)

Comment: yes my device is Jailbroken, of course, that's how I've been running Xcode (unsigned) projects on device. but with beta 5 and 6, it installs but doesn't launch